# Documentation - List of Eloquent models available properties

Tags: laravel, eloquent

It may be an obvious question, but...

Where can I find the list of all the available inherited properties for Eloquent models, such as `$table`, `$dates`, `$guarded`, `$hidden`,...?

I have been digging into the Laravel Docs (https://laravel.com/docs/master) and the Laravel API (https://laravel.com/api/master/index.html) with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent.html

Comment: Yes, that is the API link, posted on my question. But there are only the class methods listed, not the properties... Finally I am searching them with the help of the IDE, but it seems like such a great layer as Eloquent could have offered that documentation a bit more concisely. Thanks anyway

Comment: The issue mainly rests in the PHP documentation generators developers are relying on. None of them I have found support searching properties, mainly because they don't catalogue the inherited properties for a given method. Laravel uses [https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/sami](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/sami) which is no longer being maintained, and it does not seem to catalogue method properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can see that in this file:

```
ProjectRoot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
```

and files in this folder:

```
 ProjectRoot/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/
```

laravel doc : 
https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

Comment: I know the properties are in the PHP class listed... But I was wondering if there was some other 'friendly' documentation out there. Thanks anyway.